# Google Photos API returns corrupt image when accessed with BASE_URL=d

Tags: google-photos-api

Our app implements the Google Photos API to allow our user to select the images from their Google Photos album and then edit them.
However, in some cases, the image retrieved from Google Photos API `(with URL as BASE_URL=d)` is corrupted, i.e., part of the image content is grayed out.

We can't replicate the issue on our phone, so it is difficult to tell whether the image data is already corrupted in the Google Photos album, or the data becomes corrupted during the internet transmission.

We've also implement the jpg data check `(SOI = 0xffd8 and EOI = 0xffd9)` for the download image data. For a jpg source that is originally corrupt `(i.e., SOI = 0xffd8 but EOI != 0xffd9)` and then upload to Google Photos, the corrupt criterion can be correctly triggered for the download data via Google Photos API. But for the jpg images that the contents are partially grayed out as mentioned in this issue, the criterion is never triggered.

Before using Google Photos API, we've used Picasa API for about 2 years. And the corrupt image issue never happens. Does anyone have the same issue with Google Photos API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue through the Google Photos web site and contacted support about it.  They said this is a known issue that started Mar 20th and that engineers are working on it.

More detail about what I ran into:  I uploaded a photo via Backup & Sync (their desktop sync tool), which puts them in Google Drive, and have it set to replicate all pictures over to Google Photos.  The photo looks fine in Drive, but the version in Google Photos is corrupted with a large block of the photo being a solid color.